# How to add drop down list in every row of dynamic table which fetch data from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I want to add **static drop downlist** to every row of dynamic table which fetch the data from server, **How I will do this?**
I want to make same [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/10/),(**please check drop downlist type**) but it will also fetch data from server and every row of column will have drop drownlist.

**Following is updated and working code, thanks to @angu**

**Structure of drop down list.**

```
    <select >       
        <option value="1">NewJob</option>
        <option value="2">InProgress</option>
        <option value="3">CloseJon</option>
    </select>
```

**Dynamic Table**

```
    <div class="span9" id="content">        
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                    <div class="muted pull-left">Carpenter Services</div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content collapse in">
                    <div class="span12">
                         <table class="data-contacts1-js table table-striped" >
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                      <th>ID</th>
                                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                                      <th>Customer Mobile</th>
                                      <th>Customer Email</th>                                                                             
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                          <tbody>

                          </tbody>
                        </table>                                    
                   </div>


    <button id="fetchContacts1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Refresh</button>                          
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /block -->
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
             function fetchData1(){                          
                $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
                $.get("http://localhost/service/Services.php", function(data) {                    
                   var obj=JSON.parse(data);                       
                   for(var i in data){
                     var tr=$("<tr></tr>");
                     tr.append(
                            "<td>" + obj[i].b_id + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + obj[i].cust_name + "</td>" +                           
                            "<td>" + obj[i].cust_mobile + "</td>" +                           
                            "<td>" + obj[i].cust_email + "</td>"
                        );
                    tr.append("<select class='input-small'><option value='New Job'>NewJob</option><option value='WIPJob'>WIP Job</option></select>");
                     $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").append(tr);
                     i++;
                   }
                });
            }  

             $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
                $('#fetchContacts1').click(function() {
                     fetchData1();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I think you have to call nested Ajax JSON call from your  `fetchData1` function

Comment: Is your Dropdown items comes from DB? or it is static - means every tiem it will this 3 items (NewJob,inProgress,close job) ?

Comment: @Prog, It will be static, please check again I updated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use it. i think this is helpful for you

Jquery Code Generate Dynamic append Row:

```
$(function(){

    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
       var trd="";
    trd +="<tr>";
    trd +="<td>";
    trd+="<select class='input-small'><option value=''>Type</option><option value=''>Type1</option></select>";
    trd+="</td>";
    trd+="<td><input type='text'> </td>";
    trd+="<td><input type='text'> </td>";
    trd+="</tr>";
         $(".table-bordered tbody").append(trd); 
    }



});
```

[Click To Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPVUk/322/)

Comment: You can do this. Id is unique so you generate dynamic id  . you have got  dynamic data in ajax response  obj[i].b_id example: "<select id= 'selectbox_'+ obj[i].b_id >...</select>" ;

Comment: thanks, How to get id of this dynamic selected list in javascript,

Comment: I figure out like <select id='selectbox_'+obj[i].b_id onChange='update(this.id)', It is not passing the id of dynamic list but only passing selectbox_ without concatenation of obj[i].b_id. Please tell me how to concatenate 'selectbox_' to obj[i].b_id.

Comment: i think concatenate  use it   "<select id=' select_"+obj[i].b_id+" '>"...</select>"

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple createSelect functions that could work in your case. Plain JavaScript is used in those functions :-)

```js
$("body").append("createSelect() ");
$("body").append("<br>");
$("body").append(createSelect());
$("body").append("<br><br><br>");
$("body").append(" createSelectDynamic() ");
$("body").append("<br>");
var array = [{
    "value": 1,
    "text": "NewJob"
}, {
    "value": 2,
    "text": "InProgress"
}, {
    "value": 3,
    "text": "CloseJob"
}]
$("body").append(createSelectDynamic(array));

$("body").append("<br><br><br>");
$("body").append("miniTable where createSelect() used ")

$("body").append("<table><tr><td><td>2nd<td>third");
var select = createSelect();
$("td:first-child").append(select);


function createSelect() {
    var select = document.createElement("select");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = 1;
    option.text = "NewJob";
    select.add(option);

    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.value = 2;
    option2.text = "InProgress";
    select.add(option2);

    var option3 = document.createElement("option");
    option3.value = 3;
    option3.text = "CloseJob";
    select.add(option3);

    return select;
}

function createSelectDynamic(values) {

    var select = document.createElement("select");

    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = values[i].value;
        option.text = values[i].text;
        select.add(option);
    }

    return select;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```