# How to pass id of dynamic drop downlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have dynamic table, in that table every row has a dynamic dropdown list. So every dynamic dropdown list have a unique id, I have to pass this `id` to the `onChange` function. Please tell me how to do this. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541298/how-to-add-drop-down-list-in-every-row-of-dynamic-table-which-fetch-data-from-se) question for more info.

`<select id=carpender"+obj[i].b_id +"onChange='update(this.id)`

The data in the table is dynamically generated. I have to pass an `id` like `carpenter12`, if the value of `obj[i].b_id` is `12`.

**Working code I modified this code**
**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
         function fetchData1(){                          
            $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
            $.get("http://localhost/service/services.php", function(data) {
               var obj=JSON.parse(data); 
               // convert it into obj otherwise it will give    
               //alert(obj.length);
               for(var i in data){
                 var tr=$("<tr></tr>");
                 tr.append(
                        "<td>" + obj[i].b_id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + obj[i].cust_name + "</td>" +                           
                        "<td>" + obj[i].cust_mobile + "</td>" +                           
                        "<td>" + obj[i].cust_email + "</td>");
                         tr.append("<select id="+obj[i].b_id+" onChange='update(this.id)' class='input-small'><option value='New Job'>New Job</option><option value='WIP Job'>WIP Job</option><option value='Close Job'>Close Job</option></select>");
                         $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").append(tr);
                         i++;
               }
            });
        }  

         $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
            $('#fetchContacts1').click(function() {
                 fetchData1();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function update(id){
            alert(id);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `for(var i in data)` : by using this, `i` is self-incremental ans is a subset of the json object. `i++` is invalid in that case. Plus, you generate `<select id=carpender2onChange='update(this.id)' class='input-small'>`, few chances this is gonna work :)

Comment: Third error : you parse `var obj=JSON.parse(data)`, but still use `data` (which remains a string) in `for(var i in data)`